# How to get sufficient info about selection range in vim's 'VISUAL BLOCK' mode? getpos() is insufficient

Tags: vim, copy-paste, vim-plugin

I'm writing handy vim plugin which makes it possible for user to easily copy text selected in vim (vim is executed on the server over ssh) into local clipboard. In order to do that I write currently selected text into external program with ":w !" command. The issue is that the command writes whole lines that are in range denoted as '<,'> while the user doesn't always select exactly whole lines but some part of them. I found a way out and now I send `getpos("'<")[2]` and `getpos("'>")[2]` as arguments to the external program, this enables for external program to cut lines itself. But there is a problem I could not solve at the moment. Here is the case:

Text in vim buffer:

```
word1 word2 word3  
word4 word5 word6 word7  
word8 word9 word0
```

Two commands of vim: `gg0ww<C-v>jjel` and `gg0ww<C-v>jj$` select different pieces of text but the external program receives the same data in both cases (including arguments and text from stdin). I tried to google the question during some time but with no luck.

How can I make vim to put additional data for external program to distinguish examples above?

Comment: Whatever you do with `:<command>` will *always* be linewise. If you want to pass something else than whole lines to your external program you will have to yank that text and find a way to pass it to your external program via `:help system()`.

Comment: Your comment made my task too simple =)
All I have to do now is to map my hotkey to `y:silent call system('my_external_program', @0)`
Thank you  romainl!

Answer (score 1):

Don't attempt to grab the selection's corners as coordinates. Especially for a (published) plugin, there are many complications like `:set selection=exclusive`, and you need to consider byte count (as returned by `getpos()`) vs. character counts.

The easy solution is to `y`ank the active visual selection into a (temporary) register, and just work with the captured text directly. You can send this to an external program with `system()` easily.